# AngularJS not showing accented characters

Tags: mysql, angularjs, special-characters

In my MySQL database I have international strings with accented characters, such as `ñ` or `é`.

I can retrieve values from DB with Angular services and show then on the Views through Controllers, but whenever there is an accented character in a string, the whole string does not show up.

I have tried with `$sce`, with `ng-bind-html`, but always the same result. Strings with accented characters do not show.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the issue. It was not related to Angular but to **PHP reading the response from the MySQL server in a wrong character set**.

In PHP, after opening a connection `$mysqli`, you should tell it to use the same CHARSET/COLLATION as your database/table is using:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

Then special chars will be interpreted perfectly.